# cannot add multiple files using JSZip

Tags: javascript, ajax, jszip

I am using JSZip to generate a zip containing multiple files. The data is coming from the server in JSON format.
I am only getting 2 files inside the for loop instead of multiple files. The size of the array of JSON is more than 2 so I expect multiple files not just 2.

```
var zip = new JSZip();
var root = data.list.dataList;
var length = root.length;
var i;
for(i = 0; i < length; i++){                                                    
    var aFileName = "a_"+ root[i].type + "_" + root[i].orderNumber + ".xml";//just the name of the file                         
    var aContent = root[i].content; //content of file                               

    var bFileName = "b_"+ root[i].type + "_" + root[i].orderNumber + ".xml";//just the name of the file         
    var bContent = root[i].content; //content of file   

    //put files onto a folder
    zip.folder("Folder Name").file(aFileName, aContent).file(bFileName, bContent); 
}
//generate the zip with all files
var content = zip.generate();
location.href="data:application/zip;base64," + content;
```

can someone please suggest an alternative since this code only take the content of the last iteration. This is why I can only get 2 files instead of multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        var aFileName = "a_"+ root[i].type + "_" + root[i].orderNumber + "_" + i + ".xml";
        var aContent = root[i].content; //content of file

        var bFileName = "b_"+ root[i].type + "_" + root[i].orderNumber + "_" + i + ".xml";
        var bContent = root[i].content; //content of file

        //put files onto a folder
        zip.folder("Folder Name").file(aFileName, aContent).file(bFileName, bContent);
    }
```

I try similar as follows and the generated folder contains 6 files.

```
var JSZip = require("jszip");
var fs = require("fs");
var zip = new JSZip();
var root = [{type:"type1",orderNumber:"1",content:"content1"},
    {type:"type2",orderNumber:"2",content:"content2"},
    {type:"type3",orderNumber:"3",content:"content3"}];
var length = root.length;
var i;
for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
    var aFileName = "a_"+ root[i].type + "_" + root[i].orderNumber + ".xml";//just the name of the file
    var aContent = root[i].content; //content of file

    var bFileName = "b_"+ root[i].type + "_" + root[i].orderNumber + ".xml";//just the name of the file
    var bContent = root[i].content; //content of file

    //put files onto a folder
    zip.folder("json_folder").file(aFileName, aContent).file(bFileName, bContent);
}
//generate the zip with all files
var content = zip.generate({type:"nodebuffer"});

fs.writeFile("json_folder.zip", content, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

So I think maybe your problem occurs because your type and orderNumber is the same for each item so that  you overwrite your file content again and again.

Answer (score -1):

Try out plugin: http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/
Else try to wrap your loop in

```
try
{

}
catch (ex)
{
console.log(ex.message);
}
```

And have a look if he throws some errors

Comment: He asked for an alternative, so I provided an alternative framework without seeing the data he gets I cant say why just 2 files are added

Comment: Update, cant update my old comment: I used the posted framework with success. Also maybe the loop is crashing cause a property not set, thats why the try catch is for.

Comment: Can someone give me an working example similar to this issue? I am still facing this and out of idea of what to do.

Comment: Have you already tried the try-catch, also list the "data.list.datalist" object structure

Comment: I have exhausted everything I could think of plus the try/catch block...firebug shows the JSON content from each iteration perfectly fine. I found a similar question asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986432/how-to-zip-files-using-jszip-library but the suggested solution is not using the loop..I am not sure how to implement..could anyone shred some light?

Comment: issue has been fixed..thanks graphefruit for your input

Comment: Would be interested in hearing the solution;)